# Can't make even a simple drop-down-menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a layout for drop-down-menu and all the other stuff out there. I just can't figure out the easiest and cleanest way to do it. My menu is hidden because my header overflow is is hidden. If I set it to auto all the content goes crazy. Help me please.

http://codepen.io/luzlol/pen/hbijI — I'm trying over here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down list is still part of the header even if its positioned absolute, so whatever is going to show up **outside** the header but its actually **inside**, needs to be visible.

```
header {
  background: blue;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpcja)

To position an `absolute` element, you need to use `top left right bottom`.

Example:

`top:10px;`: move it towards bottom by 10 px.
`left:30px;` : shift it to the right by 30 px.

Comment: I believe visible is default for overflow, so you don't need to specify that. The #main though goes crazy even with margin and padding specified to zero when the nav is visible =(

Comment: How is it going crazy? I can't see that, and how can it go crazy? the nav is positioned absolute, it won't, and will never affect any other element.

Comment: I mean the pink container sticks to the header. I don't want my nav to affect other containers' position.

Comment: yeah, I know how to position absolute element,thanks. I can't figure out why does #main container move after making header "overflow:visible" it moves up.

Comment: @luzlol This is because the `nav` is floated left, and when an element is floated left it goes out of the normal flow of the parent div, you fixed it with `overflow:hidden;`, now we are trying to show the menu, we need to do `overflow:visible;`, so the floated element left the flow again, and the header became smaller (use border black to see it) so the `#main` went up. You can give the header a fixed height, or give the `#main` a `margin-top`.
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBGtL

Comment: I GOT IT! I made all the "major" containers to float and take 100% of width and voila! Thanks a lot for your hint!

http://codepen.io/luzlol/pen/hbijI